# Pytorch model gradients are printed correctly but copied wrongly

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I want to copy the gradients of loss, with respect to weight, for different data samples using pytorch. In the code below, I am iterating one sample each time from the data loader (batch size = 1) and collecting gradients for 1st fully connected (fc1) layer. Gradients should be different for different samples. The print function shows correct gradients, which are different for different samples. But when I store them in a list, I get the same gradients repeatedly.   Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```html
grad_list = [ ]

for data in test_loader:
  inputs, labels = data[0], data[1]
  inputs = torch.autograd.Variable(inputs)
  labels = torch.autograd.Variable(labels)

  # zero the parameter gradients
  optimizer.zero_grad()

  # forward + backward 
  output = target_model(inputs)
  loss = criterion(output, labels)
  loss.backward()

  grad_list.append(target_model.fc1.weight.grad.data)
  print(target_model.fc1.weight.grad.data)
```

[image]

Comment: Python performs assignment by reference. If you're familiar with pointers, this is basically like you are keeping a list of pointers to your gradients, when they change in the model after the next sample, the values referenced in your list of saved gradients is also changed. Instead you can use `Tensor.clone` to store a copy of the gradients, effectively snapshotting them at the time of assignment.

Comment: @jodag: Thank you so much for your great explanation;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using clone and detach instead:

```py
grad_list.append(target_model.fc1.weight.grad.clone().detach())
```

The `data` property you are appending to your list is a mutable reference to the storage of the parameter (i.e. the actual memory address and the values contained within). What you need to do is create a replica of the gradient tensor (with `clone`) and remove it from the computational graph (with `detach`) to avoid it interfering with gradient computation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input; it works great.

Comment: glad it worked! :)